# how to create custome html section in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a wordpress theme with a static header and footer but i want the user to be able to customize the other sections between header and footer , let say i have 5 sections and in each page the user should be able to decide what sections to include in the page . i tried to use page builder plugin put its not what i want exactly because once i remove a row it won't be avilable any more and i want it to be there so the user can add or delete it at any time , is there a way to store my different html sections as a custome post or a custom field??

Answer (score 0):

[Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) would work perfectly in this scenario. The plugin features over 30 field types.